# Google Developers won't let me use android.hardware.Camera or camera2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, google-play, android-manifest

**Hi**

I created a camera app and set few `<uses-feature>` 's and one of them was **android.hardware.Camera** (Deprecated). I tried to send my APK, but Google decided to put "*Supported Devices*" to **0**. I tried to do the same with **android.hardware.camera2**, but the result was the same; no supported devices.

What causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

But you'll also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And maybe also:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html for all requirements

Answer (score 2):

Please note that there's no automatic mapping between Android API packages (like android.hardware.camera2 package or the class android.hardware.Camera) and Android features such as [FEATURE_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA).

And the features have to have exactly matching strings - saying you require feature "android.hardware.Camera" is not the same as "android.hardware.camera".  The latter is the value of FEATURE_CAMERA, and the former doesn't exist in the official SDK. If you ask for it, you'll match no devices since no device lists that feature.

Similarly, there's no separate feature for the new camera2 API - if a device has a camera, it'll support camera2 on some level. So just requiring FEATURE_CAMERA is enough.  If you need a highly capable camera device, such as the FULL-level camera2 implementation, then you might want [FEATURE_CAMERA_LEVEL_FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_LEVEL_FULL).

But listing features doesn't enable you to use them - all it does is restrict what devices your app is compatible with.  You can use the camera API whether or not you list FEATURE_CAMERA (though you will need the permission, as Raymond de la Croix points out).